# Do I need to install sql server 2008 separately as the express edition is already installed with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I have installed visual studio 2010. I need to learn trigger,cursor,stored procedure,t-sql.There is no GUI for directly dealing with sql server 2008. Should I download Sql server management Studio. I am new to these and the question may seem to too irrelevent to you all but please guide me.

I have windows xp sp3 32bit computer.

Comment: The express edition you already have should be enough for learning.  I suggest you download SQL Server Management Studio Express http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593

Comment: which of the following version should I download,I have windows xp running on 32 bit. SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe
 

176.5 MB

SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe
 

168.3 MB

Answer (score 0):

Download the x86 version for your XP 32 bit operating system.

Comment: Thanks sir, will it require Windows PowerShell 1.0?

Comment: You don't need it for what you are learning, but it is nice to have. Cool stuff too learn too.